# My mySql Query is going threshhold in loader.io for 500 user in 15 sec

Tags: php, mysql

My mysql query is

```
SELECT tbl_members.id,
       tbl_members.username,
       tbl_members.confirmcode,
       tbl_members.preferredlive,
       tbl_members.sex,
       tbl_members.unlock_for,
       tbl_members.createddate,
       tbl_members.createddate,
       tbl_members.headline
FROM tbl_members
WHERE tbl_members.status ='Active'
  AND tbl_members.id <> '355'
  AND (sex = 2
       OR sex = 2)
  AND tbl_members.whocanseeme = 'visible'
ORDER BY tbl_members.id DESC
```

There are 4163 records and showing 2040 records due to sex check.

Explain mySql Query :- 
[Explain sql Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mqCm.jpg)

Its my table structure
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRpwK.jpg)

I have also added indexes in id,zipcode,suburb,status,whocanseeme,sex.

Please help So how i can make it fast and stop threshold in loder.io with max .
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you need these 2040 records? Isn't your query fast if you return only a few records?

Comment: Can you provide the execution time you measured?

Comment: Yes i need all the records. the execution time is     Average  5712 ms with 500 users in 15 sec in loder.io

Comment: You can replace `sex = 2 OR sex = 2` by `sex = 2`, but that will not change performance

Comment: In phpmyadmin, did you try profiling your query? That is a very useful tool and it would allow to see if your database itself is causing the issue.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

to improve your query performance you have to create a composit index on  status,whocanseems,sex  those 3 fields are exact matching columns so you can get better performance if you have a index in that order .

i think member id is primary key in this table

You have some large  text fields in this table and it contain large number of columns please try to normalize it else it will  show  poor performance on large data set

Comment: indeed, discovering using varchar(255) to contain all kinds of body part sizes was quite chocking to me for a number of reasons.